# get rid of commas in a list python

Tags: python, list

I have a list `[1,2,4,7,5,2]` where I want to get rid of the commas to make it `[1 2 4 7 5 2]`
how would I go about this?

np.random.randint(0,4,12) will print out like `[0 3 4 1 3 4 2 1 2 4 3 4]` and thats the kind of thing I want :)

Comment: Do you mean you want to print it like that?  You can't represent it like that in your program, because that's how lists work.

Comment: The only way to to write a for-loop and print them in this format yourself.

Comment: Actually, `str.join` is much easier (and more pythonic) than a for-loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a numpy ndarray, use:

```
np.array([1, 2, 4, 7, 5, 2])
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
out = '[' + ' '.join(str(item) for item in numbers)+ ']'
print out
```

Comment: You don't need the list comprehension in the join - getting rid of the square brackets will save time and memory.

Comment: I noticed this, but wasn't sure why.  Looks like `str(item) for item in numbers` is a generator, and the brackets actually make it create the list.  Correct?

Comment: Yes, but `join()` also accepts a generator expression so it's unnecessary.

Comment: It doesn't create the list - the `join` method iterates over the generator as it yields the values, whereas with the list comp Python created the list first then the `join` iterated over *that*

Comment: You could also use just `map(str, numbers)` which will generate a list in Python 2 and a iterator object in Python 3 (but a generator expression is probably best and is the same in both).

Answer (score 2):

```
In [7]: data = [1,2,4,7,5,2]
In [11]: '[{}]'.format(' '.join(map(str, data)))
Out[11]: '[1 2 4 7 5 2]'
```

or,

```
In [14]: str(data).replace(',','')
Out[14]: '[1 2 4 7 5 2]'
```